# Context - Error creating boxes in loop

Tags: errors, context, loops, metapost

The following code creates an array of boxes to represent an array.

```
\startMPinclusions
 input boxes ;
\stopMPinclusions

\starttext
\startluacode
function createGraphic(k,c,indH)
    local i=1
    local j=65
    context.startuseMPgraphic(name)
    context("boxjoin(a.se=b.sw; a.ne=b.nw);")
    while k[i] do
        bname=string.char(j)
        context("boxit."..bname.."(btex "..k[i].." etex)("..c[i]..");drawboxed("..bname..");")
        i=i+1
        j=j+1
    end
     context.stopuseMPgraphic()
    context.useMPgraphic(name)
end

a={51,31,4,22,23,45,23,43,54,22,11,34}
colors={"blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","blue","white","white","white"}
createGraphic(a,colors)
```

The output is

[image]

Now I want to change the colors dynamically and call the `createGraphic()` in a loop. So I wrote the following function to change the colors array.

```
function refreshColors(yellowEndIndex,redIndex,blueIndex)
        print(yellowEndIndex..","..redIndex..","..blueIndex)
        local ccnt=1
        while a[ccnt] do
                if ccnt < yellowEndIndex then
                    colors[ccnt] = "yellow"
                elseif ccnt == redIndex then
                    colors[ccnt] = "red"
                elseif ccnt == blueIndex then
                    colors[ccnt] = "blue"
                else
                    colors[ccnt] = "white"
                end
                ccnt= ccnt+1
        end
end
refreshColors(2,4,6)
createGraphic(a,colors)
```

Now, the output is

[image]

Also when I call `refreshColors()` in loop and `createGraphic()` outside there is no error.

```
for i=1,10,1 do
    refreshColors(i,0,0)
end
createGraphic(a,colors)
```

Now the output is

[image]

However, when I call `createGraphic()` inside loop, error occurs.

```
for i=1,10,1 do
    refreshColors(i,0,0)
 createGraphic(a,colors)
end
```

The error message thrown by Texworks is

```
error on line 33 in file try.tex: terminal: ! Inconsistent equation (off by -1).
```

Line 33 is

```
colors[ccnt] = "red"
```

Here is the link to the [boxes.mp](http://www.festalize.com/boxes.mp) used in the program.

I want to call the `createGraphic()` inside the loop. Why the error occurs??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You can refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help for the markdown used in this site (for including links, etc). Unfortunately, you can only add displayed pictures once you have accumulated enough reputation. But higher rep users can include the pictures for you. Also, you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: The code is incomplete (at least `\stopluacode`, etc., is missing) and I haven't managed to recreate code using `createGraphic()` that runs without error.  Could you post a proper [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?  I note that you are passing the uninitialised value `name` to startuseMPgraphic - this is a `nil` value where it should be a string, though I doubt that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem must be with `boxes.mp`
In the macro `boxit`, replace

```
@#col = cellColor;
```

with

```
@#col := cellColor;
```

This might make it work..